# TV series database architecture

Tags: database, postgresql

So we're making a service where users can keep track of what tv series they've watched. Right now have a database with seperate entries, like so (SQLAlchemy format but should be understandable):

```
class ListEntry(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'list_entries'

    uid = Column(Integer, Sequence('list_uid_seq'), primary_key=True)
    user = Column(String)          # Username
    title = Column(String)         # Series' name
    status = Column(Integer)       # Watching/completed/dropped etc
    num_watched = Column(Integer)  # Amount of episodes watched
    score = Column(Integer)        # How the user would rate the series out of 10
```

We're dealing with some 150 million entries of test data right now, and as you can imagine it's really slow, especially stuff like `SELECT * FROM list_entries WHERE user = 'name'`.

We should be able to support some 100-200 million of these entries in production. Database reads are more important than writes by far, as you can imagine. Especially finding all the entries for a certain user is an extremely common and important operation.

Right now we're using Postgres but we're open to using something else if there's a good reason for it. Nobody here is especially experienced with database work.

What kind of changes would make this faster? Any database architecture pointers you guys can provide?

Comment: Indexes: [1](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/indexes.html), [2](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/constraints.html#indexes)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_entity

Answer (score 0):

Which ever DB solution you opt for certain things will help you.

**Indexing**.
This is one of the simplest and obvious methods to reducing query times. Making sure your queries use said indexes is also critical here. *These will slow write times so you should consider these carefully.*

**Table management**. 
 This can vary by DB provider. Ensuring you don't create tables with hundreds of columns that you will never query. Making sure those that you do are well populated. Tablespaces help with the growth of data over time.

**Collections** Collections in databases tend to work much faster than standard query output, opt for these wherever you can.

Postgres is a great low cost DB solution.